# Preallocation of Array that is storing histograms in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

```
X = [];
Y = [];

for i = 1:m 

    QImg = imread(fullfile(Dir2, QueryFrames(i).name),fmt);  
    Image1 = rgb2gray(QImg);
    X = [X, imhist(Image1)];       
end

for j= 1:n

     RImg = imread(fullfile(Dir1, RefFrames(j).name),fmt);
     Image2 = rgb2gray(RImg);
     Y = [Y, imhist(Image2)];     
end
```

Can anyone show me how I can preallocate X and Y, two arrays that are storing histograms. Matlab suggests preallocation for both arrays for speed. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you know the size of the array returned by `imhist`? Does that size change with every iteration or it remains constant?

Comment: remains constant with 256 bins sorry for not making that very clear.

Answer (score 0):

By default for grayscale images (which you have), `imhist` creates a histogram using 256 bins (docs [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imhist.html)) and outputs a column vector. Therefore, unless you change the number of bins in some iterations you want X to have 256 rows. The number of columns is dictated by the number of images you are processing, here it is `m` images for the `X` variable and `n` images for the `Y` variable.

Therefore you want to initialize both variables as follows:

```
X = double(256,m);
Y = double(256,n);
```

Also, it is not recommended to use `i` or `j` as loop iterators since they can be confused for the imaginary unit.

Comment: The advice about avoiding `i` and `j` is a thing of the past. There's absolutely no harm in using them, unless you actually intend to use complex arithmetic. From [docs](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/i.html):

_For speed and improved robustness in complex arithmetic, use 1i and 1j instead of i and j._

_Since i is a function, it can be overridden and used as a variable. However, it is best to avoid using i and j for variable names if you intend to use them in complex arithmetic._

Comment: @nirvana-msu it's definitely not a thing of the past, that excerpt from the docs has remained more or less unchanged since at least R13 (2002). As long as MATLAB utilizes `i` and `j` as functions it is important that users understand the implication of using them as iterators, not because it is *wrong*, but because it can potentially be confusing. Now that the JIT compiler no longer chokes on trying to figure out if `i` is being used as a function or a variable the performance difference is essentially nonexistent.

Answer (score 0):

Store the last one first in x and y, and the loop till m-1, n-1.

```
QImg = imread(fullfile(Dir2, QueryFrames(m).name),fmt);  
Image1 = rgb2gray(QImg);
X(m) = imhist(Image1);

for i = 1:m-1
    QImg = imread(fullfile(Dir2, QueryFrames(i).name),fmt);  
    Image1 = rgb2gray(QImg);
    X(i) = imhist(Image1);       
end

RImg = imread(fullfile(Dir1, RefFrames(n).name),fmt);
Image2 = rgb2gray(RImg);
Y(n) = imhist(Image2);

for j= 1:n-1
    RImg = imread(fullfile(Dir1, RefFrames(j).name),fmt);
    Image2 = rgb2gray(RImg);
    Y(j) = imhist(Image2);     
end
```